# time-tracking and possibilities given by Jira Suite utilities

Tags: jira, transition, resolve, time-tracking

Is there any possibility with JIRA Suite utilities to realize some statistics on dashboard? I don't think so unfortunately... :-(

If I understood, time tracking (like it is explained in the JIRA Atlassian documentation) only can measure elapsed time from Open status to Resolve status (with start and stop progress transitions, including business days, working hours, ...). Is this correct ?

Because, in my workflow I did not use such transitions (both Start and Stop Progress) ... but I would like to be able to measure elapsed time from one status to another, and furthermore to establish some statistics on leader's dashboard of our team.

Answer (score 0):

Jira has time tracking features where you can log time to issues:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Logging+Work+on+an+Issue

If you haven't configured time tracking, there are some instructions here
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Time+Tracking

There are a lot of add-ons in the Atlassian Marketplace for improved time tracking
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=jira&category=&cost=&hosting=&marketingLabel=&q=timesheets

For reporting, there are lots of built in dashboard gadgets such as Resolution Time, Time to First Response, etc that can be added from the dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

"Jira Work Calendar" for time tracking in "Calendar" and timesheets: marketplace.atlassian.com/1211847. The plugin is free and really good, so please forgive me self-advertising :-).

Comment: -1: this doesn't actually answer the question, since the OP did not ask about third party components (not even about free ones).